# I want recursive relation like cakephp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have one model query where I am using two function to getting data from another two tables but now I want data of another table from previous two table.

**Model Query :**

```
$query=TemporaryBooking::where('customer_email',$mail)->with(['driverFinalPrice','negotiateDriver'])->get();
```

two functions in **TemporaryBooking :**

```
protected $table='temporary_bookings';

    public function driverFinalPrice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DriverFinalPrice');
    }
    public function negotiateDriver()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\NegotiateDriver');
    }
```

now i want driver data which is  retrieve through **NegotiateDriver**

```
protected $table='negotiate_drivers';

public function driver()
  {
     return $this->hasOne('App\Driver');
  }
```

I hope you will understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: No I don't understand your question, please be specific

Comment: @Rahul i want data which is retrieve by driver() in  NegotiateDriver using $query.

Comment: does your `with(['driverFinalPrice','negotiateDriver'])->get();` wont work?

Comment: @NewbeeDev it only shows NegotiateDriver Table data. That's the problem! It doesn't give me driver data.

Comment: @NewbeeDev I have only give reference to NegotiateDriver  model to driver model only

Comment: @NewbeeDev trying to use hasManyThrough but not working.